# Uncheck Dropdown Item at Runtime in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This seems trivial but I'm having difficulty.

A user selects an item in a dropdown and this creates a little checkmark next to the item.

I want to deselect it in my code and remove that checkmark.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just that checkmark icon or deselect the current selected item? I don't think you can have nothing selected but you can change the selection from code

Comment: I want to deselect the item selected. Restore the dropdown back to it's original state.

Comment: How do i change the selection from code?

Comment: I haven't used Unity, but usually there is a "checked" property on the individual items.  Or a "Selected items" property on the drop-down list control.

Answer (score 1):

You can change which item is selected with [`Dropdown.value`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Dropdown-value.html). At-lease, one item must be selected.

> I want to deselect the item selected. Restore it back to it's original
>   state.

Get the original item in the `Start` or `Awake` function:

```
public Dropdown dropDown;
private int originalState;

void Awake()
{
    originalState = dropDown.value;
}
```

When you want to restore it back, restore to that value you saved:

```
void restoreDropDown()
{
    dropDown.value = originalState;
}
```

Comment: @Spinteractive Don't forget to accept answer if you issue is fixed

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately original state of a dropdown is `dropdown.value = -1` and there is no way resetting it once modified. It is always greater than 0 once modified, even if you assign -1 to it.

The only workaround is to create a prefab of Dropdown and Destroy & Instantiate it from prefab when resetting. In this case you need to create all the listeners dynamically from the code which renders all editor assignments of a Dropdown useless. You need to use an initializer script.

Comment: You can set the value back to -1 as long as the dropdown has a placeholder graphic selected. 

dropdown.value=-1 does work at unselecting options.